# text encoding when combining http-conduit and scalpel-core

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Lib
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import Text.HTML.Scalpel.Core
import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding (decodeUtf8)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as L
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let address = "http://www.myriobiblos.gr/bible/nt2/matthew/1.asp"
    response <- httpLBS address
    putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++
                show (getResponseStatusCode response)
    print $ getResponseHeader "Content-Type" response
    let responseBody = getResponseBody response
```

If the code above is followed by `L8.writeFile "ch1.txt" responseBody`, then the text is saved without problem in the encoding. But if the code is followed by

```
    let innerText = scrapeStringLike responseBody
                        $ do chroot "tr" $ do text "tr"
    case innerText of
       (Just content) -> L8.writeFile "ch1.txt"  content
       Nothing -> L8.writeFile "ch1.txt" ""
```

then the resulting text is scrambled. As you can see in my import list I have tried to use the Data.Text type but I'm doing something wrong. Also when I tried to use decodeUtf8 on responseBody or on content then I took the following message:

> ch1.txt: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct to want to decode/encode UTF8 here, you only need to make small changes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Lib
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import Text.HTML.Scalpel
import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding (decodeUtf8, encodeUtf8)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let address = "http://www.myriobiblos.gr/bible/nt2/matthew/1.asp"
    response <- httpLBS address
    putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++
                show (getResponseStatusCode response)
    print $ getResponseHeader "Content-Type" response
    let responseBody = decodeUtf8 $ getResponseBody response
    let innerText = scrapeStringLike responseBody
                        $ do chroot "tr" $ do text "tr"
    case innerText of
       (Just content) -> L8.writeFile "ch1.txt"  (encodeUtf8 content)
       Nothing -> return ()
```

Decode the body to get text content, manipulate that, and encode it again to get bytes to write to disk.